# SSIS - how to select multiple columns from an excel sheet with 300+ columns

Tags: ssis

Im trying to use an Excel Source Editor to select only a handful of columns i need as opposed to the entire thing, as SSIS only lists the first 255 columns, and my Excel source has over 300.

What i did was to use Excel Source Editor, and using a SQL command for Data Access Type:

```
Select * from [Sheet1$JZ:KA]
```

Now if i want to include column A there too in the above selection, it simply wont work!

```
Select * from [Sheet1$A:A, Sheet1$JZ:KA]
```

Is there a way to do this?

thanks!